# How to count comment lines and blank lines of a java source code using Python?

Tags: python

I am a new learner.This is the program I write. But there seems a lot of problems. I want count the total lines, the blank lines, the comments lines and the code lines. But I can't run this program. And I know the way I count the comment lines is wrong.Really need some help.

```
def FileLineCount(filename):
    (shotname,extension) = os.path.splitext(filename);
    if extension == '.java' : # file type 
        file = open(filename,'r');
        allLines = file.readlines();
        file.close();

        lineCount    =0;
        commentCount = 0;
        blankCount   = 0;
        codeCount    = 0;
        for eachLine in allLines:
                if  eachLine.find('//'):  #LINECOMMENT 
                    commentCount += 1;
                else :
                    if eachLine == "":
                        blankCount += 1;
                    else :
                        codeCount += 1;
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
        self.all += lineCount;
        self.allComment += commentCount;
        self.allBlank += blankCount;
        self.allSource += codeCount;
        print filename;
        print '           Total      :',lineCount ;
        print '           Comment    :',commentCount;
        print '           Blank      :',blankCount;
        print '           Source     :',codeCount;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: first off, remove the semicolons from the end of your lines. Python doesn't use those.

Comment: If this is part of a class, you need to pass `self` as the first parameter to FileLineCount.

Comment: This is no the solution for you, just an observation. When checking for `if eachLine == "":` you should strip it if you want to count the lines with only space in them, which is often the case. Use `if eachLine.strip() == ""`.