# How to use Python to count comment line in a java source code?

Tags: python

This is my code to count blank lines ,source code lines and total lines and comment lines. I use to check if there is '//' in a line to check if it is a comment line but I know it is wrong. Because '/*...*/' can form a comment block. How to count the number of lines in a comment block?

```
def FileLineCount(self,filename):
    (filepath,tempfilename) = os.path.split(filename);
    (shotname,extension) = os.path.splitext(tempfilename);
    if extension == '.java' : # file type 
        file = open(filename);
        self.sourceFileCount += 1;
        allLines = file.readlines();
        file.close();

        lineCount    = 0;
        commentCount = 0;
        blankCount   = 0;
        codeCount    = 0;
        for eachLine in allLines:
            if eachLine != " " :
                eachLine = eachLine.replace(" ",""); #remove space    #remove tabIndent
                if  eachLine.find('//') == 0 :  #LINECOMMENT 
                    commentCount += 1;
                else :
                    if eachLine == "":
                        blankCount += 1;
                    else :
                        codeCount += 1;
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
        self.all += lineCount;
        self.allComment += commentCount;
        self.allBlank += blankCount;
        self.allSource += codeCount;
        print filename;
        print '           Total      :',lineCount ;
        print '           Comment    :',commentCount;
        print '           Blank      :',blankCount;
        print '           Source     :',codeCount;
```

Comment: I just remembered that even with '//'. That line might be not the comment line because it can be just after the normal statement. Now I am more confused.

Comment: So you're looking for lines that contain pure comment and no code?

Comment: Yes,that is what I meant

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count comment lines and blank lines of a java source code using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614571/how-to-count-comment-lines-and-blank-lines-of-a-java-source-code-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with your code e.g. you can't just remove all whitespaces (you might consider `/{whitespace}/` a comment). I'm not gonna provide actual code but this should give you a rough idea.

```
for each line of code  
1. Remove all white space from the beginning (left trimming).  
2. If mode is not multi-line and the line contains `//` increment counter.  
3. else if mode is not multi-line and the line contains `/*` go to multi-line mode.  
4. else if mode is multi-line  
           increment coutner
           if line contains `*/` exit multi-line mode
```

The conditions could be simplified, but I think you can get it to work.